# MYSQL database create using knex

Tags: mysql, knex.js

**How to create database using knex npm?**

Here it is MYSQL query

```
create database 'test'
```

I want to convert this query using knex.

Comment: **knex.raw('create database test').then((resp) => { })** using this query create database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special API for creating DB in `knex`, probably because `knex` usually connects to already created DB and to be honest database creation is pretty rare operation.

Npm package `knex-db-manager` (https://vincit.github.io/knex-db-manager/) can do also database maintenance tasks and has separate superuser and normal user connection.